# In JPA, Using only one get method, will be able to fetch data from different tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have only one `getCustomerUsingID().`

Using the above method, dynamically I need to fetch data from different table.

Example : 
In JPA, `getCustomerUsingID()` fetch data from OrangeCustomerTable and also from AppleCustomerTable using the id which i send in parameter. is it possible?

Note:

1. No DAO Class should be used.
2. Entity class has mapping with tables.

Comment: Are you giving us an assignment? Stackoverflow is not meant for discussions.
If you can add some code and what problems you are facing, that would be cool.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now go off and do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You can write custom (maybe HQL) queries, write custom Spring Data JPA repositories / Projections, write Spring Data JPA Specifications or define mappings like this.

Comment: Could we able to do with Criteria API or JPQL? Which one ll be best

Comment: Of course it's also possible with Criteria or JPQL. You only have to define the result and define the query joining the tables you need. Just take a look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

Comment: There is no real 'best solution'. It depends on your needs. If you need an abstract and portable solution, keep it as abstract as possible (JPA). If you need database specific functions and want to gain the most performant query possible you have to go the native way.